# Kendo DropDownList issue when page scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two Kendo DropDownLists in my page. The dropdown opens fine when visible but, if the dropdown is at the bottom of the page and I need to scroll, the dropdown won't open. This happens only in **FireFox**

Also If the dropdown is visible at the top of the page and working, but I change the window's size the same problem occurs.

To put it in easy words, whenever the browser scroll bars appears only in **FireFox**, the dropdown won't work.

Without ScrollBars:
[image]

With ScrollBars:
[image]

**I need some help with this.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solve by adding a piece of css. In case someone else experiences this issue, [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/q1%2714-release---popup-bug-in-firefox) is the link with the fix.